# DevOps Error when try to release SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: azure-devops, ssas, ssas-tabular, devops-services

We are using SSIS packages and SSAS tabular models for our Business Intelligence project and Azure DevOps is the CI/ CD environment. Our databases are in SQL server 2016 and using Visual Studio 2017 and [SSDT tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) for building pakages.

We can successfully build and release SSIS packages from Azure DevOps but when it comes to analysis service,Tabular models are failing when try to release even after successful build, due to the following error:

```
##[error]Task_InternalError The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SaveChanges": "Encountered an invalid type for a default value."
```

[image]

If anyone has encountered or resolved this issue, please share thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a recent thread in #github regarding same issue "Deployment broken #2" and realized that this is caused due an agent upgrade in DevOps.
You have to install new version of agent in DevOps and can create a new Task under the Release.

See article:
[Deployment broken #2](https://github.com/avdbrink/VSTS-SSAS-Extension/issues/2)